# Java SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returns null

Tags: java, maven

Trying to get a SplashScreen working in Java; unfortunately without any success.
I have read many threads about it but almost all of them are pretty old.

I have set up a maven project and was following the Sun/Oracle Tutorial about the SplashScreen.
I am using the maven-jar-plugin to create my manifest.mf file. In there I specified the main class and the image file as shown in the tutorial.

Extract of my pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My manifest.mf file contains the following two additional lines:

```
Main-Class: com.mycompany.splashscreen.MySplashScreen
SplashScreen-Image: images/java-duke-logo.jpg
```

I copied the image in `src/main/resources/images` followed maven standard directory recommendation.

Nevertheless, the following line:

```
final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
```

always returns null!

In the generated jar file the image was put in the package "images".

Kindly asking for a lead to get it work. Thanks.

(My working environment: MacOSX 10.13.6, jdk16, NetBeans 12.3)

Comment: how is the code of that SplashScreen class?

Comment: can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/SplashDemoProject/src/misc/SplashDemo.java

Comment: no, it can't. and, as you can see, they make it clear that in that example, it can be null

Comment: there should be a reason why the method call returns null but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work by editing the [original project](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/misc-SplashDemoProject.zip), using the following directory structure:

```
└───misc-SplashDemoProject
    │   pom.xml
    │
    └───src
        └───main
            ├───java
            │   └───com
            │       └───mycompany
            │           └───splashscreen
            │                   SplashDemo.java
            │
            └───resources
                ├───images
                │       splash.gif
                │
                └───META-INF
                        MANIFEST.MF
```

**`pom.xml`**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>spashscreen</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Java 9 or later
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>16</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.mycompany.splashscreen.SplashDemo</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**`MANIFEST.MF`**:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Codebase: *.oracle.com
Permissions: sandbox
Application-Name: Splash Demo
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.gif
```

I've edited [`SplashDemo.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/SplashDemoProject/src/misc/SplashDemo.java) by replacing:

```java
package misc;
```

with:

```java
package com.mycompany.splashscreen;
```

---

Running:

```sh
mvn clean install
```

Creates the executable `.jar` file in `misc-SplashDemoProject/target`

Comment: update: for some reason NetBeans is not showing the splashscreen, if I run the project! If I execute the jar file directly it shows the splash screen. Any idea how to convince NetBeans to behave correctly???

Comment: I don't really use NetBeans so I can't help with that. But you should be able to build your project from the command line.