How to use a JAR file to display a splash screen?
package misc;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SplashDemo extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    static void renderSplashFrame(Graphics2D g, int frame) {
        final String[] comps = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        g.fillRect(120,140,200,40);
        g.setPaintMode();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Loading "+comps[(frame/5)%3]+"...", 120, 150);
    }
    public SplashDemo() {
        super("SplashScreen demo");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Menu m1 = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Exit");
        m1.add(mi1);
        mi1.addActionListener(this);
        this.addWindowListener(closeWindow);

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mb);
        mb.add(m1);
        
        //
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        if (splash == null) {
            System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            renderSplashFrame(g, i);
            splash.update();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(90);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        splash.close();
        
        // setVisible(true);
        // toFront();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    private static WindowListener closeWindow = new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            e.getWindow().dispose();
        }
    };
}

In JAR's main class:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SplashDemo(); //splash with image
    ...

When I run it from the console, I get

SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null

The project folders are as follows
project root > src > misc > SplashDemo.java
project root > src > main > resources > META-INF > MANIFEST.MF
// made a few locations for the picture to pick up from somewhere.
project root > src > main > resources > images > `image here`
project root > images > `image here`
project root > src > images > `image here`

and manifest file
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.MainClassName
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.gif

pom file
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.creator</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies> ... </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>main.MainClassName</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>

However, the application did not create a splash screen when launched via the manifest file option, that is, the getSplashScreen method returns null. How to fix it?
The created JAR file contains an images folder with image in the root.

Have a look at the post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67685595/java-splashscreen-getsplashscreen-returns-null

@AdilShaikh I have added in the maven-jar-plugin the line  <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile> as it shown in the link but the error is still the same. What is interesting is that in generated jar in the MANIFEST file there is no more line SplashScreen-Image - is that how it's supposed to be?

most probably the MANIFEST.MF file is not being used at all, since being created by Maven. Open the JAR file (WinZip, 7-zip, jar, or similar) and check the content of the MANIFST.MF file - most probably you must add the splashscreen attribute to the manifest entry in the pom file (sorry, I do not use Maven)

@user85421 yes that works, thanks, but there must be a reason why it doesn't work with maven

you used Maven to create a manifest file (by adding <manifest> entry), so it is creating it, the provided one is not used (again, I do not use Maven, just guessing)

@user85421 probably you are right. I opened manifest from jar and there was Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.4.2 so it recreated it and didn't use the file entry from source code manifest file.

The following works for me with the SplashDemo class from the tutorial you seem to be using:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>misc.SplashDemo</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <SplashScreen-Image>splash.gif</SplashScreen-Image>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Demo zip is HERE (mvn package && java -jar target/misc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
